# Empty values in Elasticsearch query string

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using ES for my Laravel app in order to search a table/type.

My users can search a total of 5 columns which means that there can be a total of 31 query combinations.

So my question is now if I can use the same query but dont provide ES with all the seach params. Or somehow write dynamic queries.

Eg:

```
'filtered' => [
  'query' => [
    'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
   ],
   'filter'=> [
     'bool' => [
       'must' => [
         ['term' => [ 'type' => 1] ],
         ['term' => [ 'state' => 22] ],
         ['term' => [ 'city' => ] ], (empty)
         [
           'range' => [
             'price' => [
                'gte' => , (empty)
                'lte' => , (empty)
             ]
           ]
         ]
       ]
     ]
  ],
],
```

Otherwise I have to write 31 different combinations of this query - If ES dont have anything that can help me. And I can use Laravels eloquent ORM for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Elasticquent`

Elasticquent makes working with Elasticsearch and Eloquent models easier by mapping them to Elasticsearch types. You can use the default settings or define how Elasticsearch should index and search your Eloquent models right in the model.

Elasticquent uses the official Elasticsearch PHP API. To get started, you should have a basic knowledge of how Elasticsearch works (indexes, types, mappings, etc).

https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent

Comment: I am using that very package. But it doesnt work like ORM eloquent. 

$books = Book::searchByQuery(array('match' => array('title' => 'Moby Dick')));

Users can search/filter out products by filtering 5 different values. If I would match every type of combination that would mean that I would have to write 31 combinations/queries and only use the one needed